# How can I enable IMAP modules in PHP on Mac OS 10.8

Tags: php, macos, apache, imap

I have Apache server on Mac OS 10.8. I need module IMAP to be enabled in PHP. I followed this instruction http://blog.xeonxai.com/2009/12/03/160/. I have installed **imap.so** and link it in **php.ini** file like this

```
extension=/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/imap.so
```

But I cannot get IMAP modules when print out `phpinfo()` as well as `imap_open` function. What's wrong with my web server ?

Thanks for helping !

Comment: did you restart the server?

Comment: Yes I restarted server but nothing happened :(

Comment: Do you use an own installation of PHP or the Mac's integrated installation?

Answer (score 7):

This is what I did to have the IMAP module working:

1. Install php56 with IMAP enabled using brew: `brew install php56 --with-imap`
2. Edit http.conf and replace the line loading PHP (LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so) with the newly installed PHP: `LoadModule php5_module    /usr/local/opt/php56/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`
3. Restart apache: `sudo apachectl restart`

Comment: On EL Capitan I had to do: `brew install homebrew/php/php56 --with-imap` It will also install all dependencies: Installing dependencies for `homebrew/php/php56: libpng, freetype, gettext, icu4c, imap-uw, jpeg, libxml2, unixodbc, readline`

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. Now it shows this: `Warning: Use php@5.6 instead of deprecated homebrew/php/php56
Warning: php@5.6: this formula has no --with-imap option so it will be ignored!`